# How to count aggregate data from RSForm submission values with Joomla's query building methods?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, sql, rsform, pivot

| user | SubmissionId | FormId | FieldName | FieldValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bob | 2 | 16 | state | **mystate1** |
| bob | 2 | 16 | qda | **myqad1** |
| bob | 2 | 16 | city | **mycity1** |
| rob | 3 | 16 | state | mystate2 |
| rob | 3 | 16 | qda | myqad1 |
| rob | 3 | 16 | city | mycity1 |
| jac | 4 | 16 | state | mystate1 |
| jac | 4 | 16 | qda | myqad3 |
| jac | 4 | 16 | city | mycity1 |
| sara | 5 | 20 | state | mystate1 |
| sara | 5 | 20 | qda | myqad1 |
| sara | 5 | 20 | city | mycity2 |

I want to count the number of submissions where `formid` is `16`, `state` is `mystate1`, `qda` is `myqad1` , and `city` is `mycity1`.

In my example, the count should be **1** because only `SubmissionId` number `2` satisfies all requirements.

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
//$query->select('COUNT(*)');
$query->select($db->quoteName('FieldValue') . ' IN ("mycity1")');

$query->from($db->quoteName('#__rsform_submission_values'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('formid') .' IN ("16")');
$query->where($db->quoteName('FieldName') .' IN ("state","qda","city")');
$query->where($db->quoteName('FieldValue') . ' IN ("mystate1","myqad1","mycity1")');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($results as $value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $data) {
        echo $data."<br />";
    }
}
```

Here's my attempted query, but it doesn't produce the count that I want:

```
SELECT COUNT(SubmissionId)  
FROM my_submission_values 
WHERE FormId = '16' 
   AND FieldName ='state' 
   AND FieldValue = 'mystate1' 
   AND FieldName = 'qda' 
   AND FieldValue = 'myqad1' 
   AND FieldName = 'city' 
   AND FieldValue ='mycity1'
```

Answer (score 0):

For all future mysql support questions (whether on Stack Overflow or on Joomla Stack Exchange), you will enjoy more, faster and more accurate answers if you include a fiddle of your table schema in an online demo link.  For example: [<kbd>db-fiddle</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qnmJQugG9f8MsCw2RYdUTw/0)

As for this specific task, RSForm's `#__rsform_submission_values` table is built as a Unified Content Model.  This means you will need to group related rows and use aggregate functions to filter and isolate what you need.  This technique is commonly referred to as a [<kbd>PIVOT</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot).  You can find my other [Joomla-related pivot queries on Joomla Stack Exchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12352%20%5Bpivot%5D).

I am rather surprised that your `submission_values` table contains a `user` column.  This is not the standard table structure designed by RSForm.  I am going to write my answer with the knowledge that the user column comes from a related table.  I am going to show this best practice so that:

1. you have an opportunity to un-hack your table structure if you have hacked it and
2. researchers who have a standard table structure can immediately use my snippets.

There will be a few ways to execute the required technique.  I will show a classic pivot query with an `INNER JOIN` and another query that uses a subquery with `EXIST` to isolate the unique counts.  If `Username` is not a unique field in the `submissions` table, then find a unique field in that table to count.  **I have tested these queries and php scripts to be successful.**

Raw Query via INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.Username)
FROM lmonp_rsform_submissions s
INNER JOIN lmonp_rsform_submission_values sv
    ON s.FormId = sv.FormId
        AND s.SubmissionId = sv.SubmissionId
WHERE s.FormId = 16
GROUP BY s.Username
HAVING MAX(IF(FieldName = 'state', FieldValue, NULL)) = 'mystate1'
    AND MAX(IF(FieldName = 'qda', FieldValue, NULL)) = 'myqad1'
    AND MAX(IF(FieldName = 'city', FieldValue, NULL)) = 'mycity1'
```

Raw Query via EXISTS(subquery):

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM lmonp_rsform_submissions s
WHERE s.FormId = 16
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT FormId
        FROM lmonp_rsform_submission_values sv
        WHERE s.FormId = sv.FormId
            AND s.SubmissionId = sv.SubmissionId
        GROUP BY s.Username
        HAVING MAX(IF(FieldName = 'state', FieldValue, NULL)) = 'mystate1'
            AND MAX(IF(FieldName = 'qda', FieldValue, NULL)) = 'myqad1'
            AND MAX(IF(FieldName = 'city', FieldValue, NULL)) = 'mycity1'
    )
```

Now, I'll present the Joomla query builder syntax to generate the above queries.
Both snippets will share these variables as a means to allow you to customize the sql conditions without scanning through the full query block.

```
$formId = 16;
$having = [
   'state' => 'mystate1',
   'qda' => 'myqad1',
   'city' => 'mycity1'
];
```

Joomla Query Builder with INNER JOIN:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
   ->select("COUNT(DISTINCT s.Username)")
   ->from("#__rsform_submissions s")
   ->innerJoin("#__rsform_submission_values sv ON s.FormId = sv.FormId AND s.SubmissionId = sv.SubmissionId")
   ->where("s.FormId = " . $formId)
   ->group("s.Username");
foreach ($having as $column => $value) {
   $query->having("MAX(IF(FieldName = " . $db->q($column) . ", FieldValue, NULL)) = " . $db->q($value));
}

//echo $query->dump();  // uncomment to see the rendered sql
$db->setQuery($query);
echo $db->loadResult();
```

Joomla Query Builder with EXISTS(subquery):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$subquery = $db->getQuery(true)
   ->select("FormId")
   ->from("#__rsform_submission_values sv")
   ->where(["s.FormId = sv.FormId", "s.SubmissionId = sv.SubmissionId"])
   ->group("s.Username");
foreach ($having as $column => $value) {
   $subquery->having("MAX(IF(FieldName = " . $db->q($column) . ", FieldValue, NULL)) = " . $db->q($value));
}
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
   ->select("COUNT(1)")
   ->from("#__rsform_submissions s")
   ->where(["s.FormId = " . $formId, "EXISTS ($subquery)"]);

//echo $query->dump();  // uncomment to see the rendered sql
$db->setQuery($query);
echo $db->loadResult();
```

I did not benchmark these queries, so if you find one of them to be noticeably slow, you might try the other.

[@itoctopus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916491/itoctopus)/[@itoctopus](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/7867/itoctopus) seems [rather scathing of use of DISTINCT](https://www.itoctopus.com/on-the-careless-usage-of-mysql-distinct-in-joomla-com-content), so it may be less performant.

Comment: yes User is not my field in table i add this to any body that not work by rsform @mickmackusa

Answer (score 0):

tank you @mickmackusa I change to this code

```
    SELECT count(DISTINCT a.SubmissionId) 
    FROM `#__rsform_submission_values` a 
    JOIN `jwqt5_rsform_submission_values` b 
    ON(a.submissionid=b.submissionid) 
    JOIN `#__rsform_submission_values` c 
    ON(b.submissionid=c.submissionid) 
    WHERE a.FormId= '16' 
    AND a.FieldName='state' AND a.FieldValue='mystate1' 
    AND b.FieldName='qda' AND b.FieldValue='myqad1' 
    AND c.FieldName='city' AND c.FieldValue='mycity1'
```

my total count of (state is **mystate1** and qda is **myqad1** and city is **mycity1**) is ok (count is 1)

I want to count **mycity1** and qda is **myqad1** (count is 2)Separated (by variable)
and Separated count **mystate1** that qda is **myqad1** (count is 2) (by variable)

Comment: I do not recommend this technique.  You are joining a very large (or will be eventually very large) table to itself 2 additional times.  I expect my solution to be more efficient.  The implementation of a "pivot query" is the professional way to consolidate the related rows and deliver the desired result.