# How to conditionally add filters to my query of the rsform_submission_values table?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql, rsform, jinput

```
$FormId=23;
$qustioan1=qka1;

<form method="post" action="#">
    <select name="state" onChange="irancitylist(this.value);">
        <option value="">--select state --</option>
        <option value="mystate">mystate</option>
    </select>

    <select name="city" id="city">
        <option value="">--select city--</option>
        <option value="mycity">mycity</option>
    </select> 


    <button type="submit" name="submit" >go to select</button>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $state=$_POST["state"];
        $city=$_POST["city"];
    }
```

If the user selects a `state` and a `city`, do this query:

```
$db->setQuery(SELECT count(DISTINCT a.SubmissionId) 
FROM `jwqt5_rsform_submission_values` a 
JOIN `jwqt5_rsform_submission_values` b 
ON(a.submissionid=b.submissionid) 
JOIN `jwqt5_rsform_submission_values` c 
ON(b.submissionid=c.submissionid) 
WHERE a.FormId= '$FormId' 
AND a.FieldName='state' AND a.FieldValue='$state' //mystate
AND b.FieldName='$qustioan1' AND b.FieldValue='yes' 
AND c.FieldName='city' AND c.FieldValue='$city'"); //mycity
$Q1answer = $db->loadResult();
```

Otherwise, if the user selects only a `state`, do this query:

```
$db->setQuery(SELECT count(DISTINCT a.SubmissionId) 
FROM `jwqt5_rsform_submission_values` a 
JOIN `jwqt5_rsform_submission_values` b 
ON(a.submissionid=b.submissionid) 
WHERE a.FormId= '$FormId' 
AND a.FieldName='state' AND a.FieldValue='$state' //mystate
AND b.FieldName='$qustioan1' AND b.FieldValue='yes' );
$Q1answer = $db->loadResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the code from [my earlier code](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/28830/12352), then you only need to write a dynamic `$having` array to generate the correct HAVING clause.  I must note that your current coding attempt is not stable/secure.  You are receiving user-supplied data from `$_POST` and feeding it directly into your raw sql.  This means that there are no validating or sanitising steps to protect your application.

Also, you have some typos to fix.  `qka1` is a string that must be wrapped in quotes at `$qustioan1=qka1;`.

To avoid re-posting my previous answer, I'll only show how to build your `$having` array.

```
$formId = 23;
$having = ['qka1' => 'yes'];

$input = Factory::getApplication()->input;
$state = $input->post('state', '', 'string');
if ($state) {
    $having['state'] = $state;
}
$city = $input->post('city', '', 'string');
if ($city) {
    $having['city'] = $city;
}
```

The `foreach()` loop on the `$having` array will correctly apply the chosen filters into your query.

This gives you clean, professional, maintainable code without having to dig deeply into your query building block of code.